# How to parse my input after generating Lexer and Parser using ANTLR4

Tags: javascript, node.js, antlr, antlr4

I am using "PLSQL.g4" grammar file and I have generated PLSQLLexer.js and PLSQLParser.js using ANTLR4 tool.

Now, How can i move forward in order to parse my SQL queries.( I am using nodejs)

```
Example
Select * from employee where name = 'xxx'; //I want to parse this query
```

I have written this code till now:

```
var antlr4 = require('antlr4/index'),
plsqlLexer = require('./PLSQLLexer').PLSQLLexer,
plsqlParser = require('./PLSQLParser').PLSQLParser;

var input = "Select * from employee where name = 'cse'";
var chars = new antlr4.InputStream(input);
var lexer = new plsqlLexer(chars);
var tokens = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new plsqlParser(tokens);
parser.buildParseTrees = true;
//Now to generate a tree which method i need to call?
```

[link for PLSQLParser.js](https://jsfiddle.net/vn5gb40o/) Generated parser using antlr4

Note: I am new to ANTLR4

Comment: does this help? https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md#how-do-i-run-the-generated-lexer-andor-parser

Comment: With the help of same link, I have generated lexer and parser for PLSQL grammar. After that, I am unable to find/understand how to move further to parse my sql query. Can i have more input/Examples on how to do this?

Comment: What is your problem, when doing it like described there? maybe you should show what you tried.

Comment: Example provided in the link uses "parser.StartRule()" function. If i use the same , It is throwing the error like "StartRule" is not a function.(This is because there is no function with this name).
Can i post my code what i have written?

Comment: did you click the posted link? in that section `parser.MyStartRule();` is called... but you should edit your question to reflect your concrete problem. Maybe include the generated parser...

Comment: In the same link (Bottom), He has used "parser.StartRule()". However, I have tried both functions which are vain. 
I am unable to post the code of generated parser as it has more than 4000 lines of code.

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vn5gb40o/) for generated parser.

Comment: First... you should put as much information as possible into your question (also JSFiddle= links... https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md#how-do-i-get-the-runtime-in-my-browser Did you follow what is given in this section? Is the antlr js runtime loaded?

Comment: Sorry and Thanks for the instructions.Yes, I followed the same and I have loaded runtime.I updated the same in question.

Comment: try var tree = `parser.file();` instead of  `parser.MyStartRule();`

Comment: I am getting this, when i run using "parser.file()"  
    line 1:0 token recognition error at: 'S'  
    line 1:6 token recognition error at: ' *'  
    line 1:7 token recognition error at: ' f'  
    line 1:1 mismatched input 'elect' expecting 'create'  
    line 1:11 token recognition error at: ' e'  
    line 1:19 token recognition error at: ' w'  
    line 1:24 token recognition error at: ' n'  
    line 1:28 token recognition error at: ' ='  
    line 1:29 token recognition error at: ' ''  
    line 1:33 token recognition error at: '''

Comment: next try ;) `var tree = parser.parse();`

Comment: and yes, you have to implement that Listeners/Visitors

Comment: @Meiko If i try, "parser.parse()" it is throwing "Undefined is not a function" error!
For implementing Listeners/Visitors, Can i have a example(s) other than which are provided in that link?

Comment: did you solve the issue?